# How do I configure tinydns (with fefe's IPv6 patch) to listen on IPv6 address?

Tags: networking, ipv6, djbdns

I'm setting up my network to support IPv6. I have static IPv6 addresses assigned to each interface of my router, and radvd advertising different prefixes on each interface. The next step would be to get my dnscache (from djbdns) working on IPv6. Said dnscache has fefe's IPv6 patch applied, so I assume it should work with IPv6. However, I can't find any documentation online on how to make the patched dnscache listen on IPv6.

How do I configure tinydns and dnscache to listen on IPv6 too?

Comment: Alternate answer: `dnsmasq` supports IPv6 natively and will also offer router advertisements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two different tinydns processes if you want "IPv6 too": one binds IPv4 and the other IPv6.
You can share the same "tinydns/root" directory between them, so they publish DNS records from the same database and you avoid duplication of data.

To bind IPv6 on the second instance, you just need to set the IP variable to the desired IPv6 address.

If you use daemontools to run djbdns, just do this:

```
# create two tinydns instances for IPv4 and IPv6
cd /var/service
svc -d tinydns
mv tinydns tinydns4
cp -r tinydns4 tinydns6
# update config for the IPv6 instance
echo 2a00:1450:4001:c02::6a > tinydns6/env/IP
# start both instances
svc -u tinydns*
```

Comment: Thanks. I had figured that out through reading the source code and meant to come back here to post the answer, but you beat me to it. Another thing that stumped me: on Debian, Ubuntu, etc. the IPv6 patch is not included in the djbdns package. You have to install `dbndns` to get djbdns + fefe's IPv6 patch.

Comment: Yes, debian forked 'dbndns' with such patches when DJB made djbdns public domain. Consequently, Ubuntu got it too. Most operating systems however still use djbdns, with the relevant patches.